# NLTK pos_tagger doesn't recognize language of text

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

I am getting a **NotImplementedError** message from NLTK that says that NLTK pos_tag only supports English and Russian, but my corpus is in English. Has anybody seen this problem before? Could this be due to character encoding?

Answer (score 0):

This is now a [closed issue](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/2184). The solution was implemented in a [PR](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/2186/files#diff-34022dd7c15afeba0f26319ac39f349dR180) where the `'lang'` parameter was passed to `_pos_tag` in `pos_tag_sents` in `nltk/tag/__init__.py`.

Try updating `nltk` or just add the `lang` parameter to the suggested code.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have the latest version of NLTK installed and I have tried adding the lang parameter to the code, but it still gives me the same error. I guess I'll have to raise this as an issue in the repo.

Comment: Is there any update on this. I tried updating the nltk and also the lang parameter was already added in the init_.py file. I still get the error "Currently, NLTK pos_tag only supports English and Russian (i.e. lang='eng' or lang='rus')"